# overflow: hidden did not hide

Tags: jquery, css

```
<style>

    .divTable {
        display: table;
        float: right;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: #0082CA;
    }

    .divTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }

    .divTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }

    .menuLink, .icon {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 10px 10px;

    }

    .menuLink {
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 40px;
        display: none;  
        overflow:hidden;                
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .menuLink a
    {
        font-size:large;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    .divTableRow:hover
    {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .icon 
    {
        width: 30px;
    }

    .icon img 
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('.menuLink, .icon')
            .mouseover(function () {

                $(".menuLink").stop(true, false).fadeIn(280);
                $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
                    width: "300px",
                    opacity: "1"
                });
            })

            .mouseleave(function () {

                $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
                    width: "0px",
                    opacity: "1",
                });

            });
    });

</script>
```

```
<div class="divTable">

    <div class="divTableBody">

        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="menuLink"><a href="http://www.google.com">Link1</a></div>

            <div class="icon">
                <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="menuLink"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Link2</a></div>

            <div class="icon">
                <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="menuLink"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Link3</a></div>

            <div class="icon">
                <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="menuLink"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">Link4</a></div>

            <div class="icon">
                <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I trying to create a menu with mouseover and mouseleave using jQuery. When user mouseover the menu image, it will slide out horizontal toward left and display the menu text. When the mouseleave, the menu text will slide back and hidden.

I have used overflow: hidden. However, my menu does not completely hid the text and resulting the initial menu width expand. can anyone explain to me how can i hide the menu text?

Thank you,

Comment: http://codepen.io/mostofa/full/oLpmPL/

I am not understand what you say and what the problem here ? 
Are You want ? when you hover ** link 1***  show link one text after when you hover ** link 2 ** then ** hide link 1 ** and show ** link 2 **. I am right ?

Comment: @MDMostofa I tried overflow but it does not work. 
The problem is when I mouseover on the icon, a menu slide out. when i mouseleave, the menu should slide back and hidden but for the above code, the menu did slide back but it does not stay hidden and it increase the initial menu width. 

hope you understand what i trying to said.

Comment: @MDMostofa yes, i dont know why the Link Text remain out there after i mouseleave

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to acomplish. Is it the "L" letter which remains after the menu retreats back, that bothers you?

Comment: @EddNewGate yes. any idea to fix it? because of that "L" the menu width increase.

Comment: @noobGuy .menuLink, .icon { display: table-cell; padding: 10px 0px; } add 2nd parameter of padding to 0px and it removes the increased width, as well the letter "L" .

Comment: @EddNewGate omg!! thank a lot !! it work =D

Comment: @noobGuy glad I could help :)

Comment: @EddNewGate last help because i really very bad in CSS, can you tell me how should i change: 

1) Align the text and image vertical middle
2) where should i add my padding so that the text and image stick to corner

Comment: @noobGuy  I didn't fully understand this :" 1) Align the text and image vertical middle ".  You want your menu to be in the middle of screen ? Not on right corner ?

Comment: @EddNewGate yes, the text and image to be vertical-middle, not at corner or near borderline

Comment: @noobGuy for that, you change in .DivTable the float:right  to margin: auto

Comment: @EddNewGate i think i got it. thank a lot!! really appreciate it =)

Comment: @MDMostofa thank you, your website is great =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding display: none with your opacity settings. So while the text has opacity it will display. You should change:

```
    .mouseleave(function () {

        $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "0px",
            opacity: "1"
        });

    });
```

to:

```
    .mouseleave(function () {

        $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
            width: "0px",
            opacity: "0",
            "padding-left": "0px",
            "padding-right": "0px"
        });
    });
```

Also change:

```
        .mouseover(function () {

            $(".menuLink").stop(true, false).fadeIn(280);
            $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
                width: "300px",
                opacity: "1"
            });
        })
```

to:

```
        .mouseover(function () {

            $(".menuLink").stop(true, false).fadeIn(280);
            $('.menuLink').stop(true, false).animate({
                width: "300px",
                opacity: "1",
                "padding-left": "10px",
                "padding-right": "10px"
            });
        })
```

**Short explanation:**

By setting the opacity to zero, the paddings remained displayed. Paddings did not show before, because the item had display: none (opposed to opacity: 0) By removing and adding the padding in the animation process it looks as intended now.

Comment: no, i set it "1" on purpose to debug why the menu width increase. sorry for not changing it to 0. so when the opacity is set to "0". the width of the menu change because of the text

Comment: By the way why don't you use the css :hover selector? You don't really need javascript for this.

Comment: New answer after looking at Mostofa's Fiddle. The issue you are having is because of the padding of .menuLink. Set the padding to 0 (left and right) and the problem is solved!

Comment: Basically display: none doesn't show the padding and opacity:0 does. That is the cause of your issue.